# How do I get rid of old accounts I don't use, only one?

Tags: google-account, account-management

I added new accounts when I first started, I only use one now and would like to dispose of the others.

Answer (score 1):

You can [delete your Google account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046?hl=en) anytime.

See this to [Delete your Gmail address](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61177?hl=en).